# data translating issues

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have these two table here in ssms:

- one is called client table, which have a column called city, and it is really city name, like new york, etc.
- Another table is called city table, it has city's ID and city name. such as CityID:1 City: New york.

So in my Client table, I know how to create another column called CityID, but how can I populate the CityID column in the client table, entering them by searching the CityID in the City table?

Comment: Is `city.name` a unique column? If not, you may have to use other data to figure out whether (for example) a `client` with `city` = "Springfield" is from Springfield, Illinois; Springfield, Ohio; Springfield, North Tacoma; etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the following statement:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.CityID = B.CityID 
FROM dbo.client AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.city AS B 
       ON A.city = B.City;
```

If you don't want a [case/blank spaces] sensitive update (`' New York   ' = 'NEW YORK'`) use this statement:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.CityID = B.CityID 
FROM dbo.client AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.city AS B 
       ON rtrim(ltrim(upper(A.city))) = rtrim(ltrim(upper(B.City)));
```